# How to read and append multiple cells from different excel files in python ?( in a simpler way)?)

Tags: python, excel

---edit ---
From the code given by ***oh_my_lawdy***  (THANks!!) i got the result seen in picture. It's like joining lists in a dataframe but gets NAN for every column i add

--- [final df with code by oh_my_lawdy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XOOI6.png)

-end of edit--

i'm trying to get data (multiple  cells from one sheet) from different excel files (Daily report) and make **only one excel file with daily data to use it in plots (actual vs budget, forecasting...)**

**So Far i can get the results i want**, but i think is not an efficient or "elegant" way to do it.

I read excel files with a FOR  and I defined a **Function** for read specific cells from daily report, pass this function for the FOR loop, and append data through the loop, that creates one column dataframes, and then i use CONCAT to get just one dataframe, then i write output to excel file.

I need to **read at least 8 cells from this daily report**, each one would be a column in a Dataframe, so coding is really long, and i'm thinking using this code for other reports but i'm feeling like it's not "clean"

For now, daily reports don't change cell positions

Any help would be appreciated (maybe function could read several cells at once?)

Reading excel files

```
import os
import pandas as pd

path = os.getcwd()
files = os.listdir(path)
files

files_xls = [f for f in files if f[-3:] == 'xls']
files_xls
```

Function

```
def read_produccion(files_xls, column="H", row=17):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Producción"])
def read_inv_i(files_xls, column="G", row=10):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Inventario Inicial"])
def read_inv_f(files_xls, column="G", row=68):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Inventario Final"])
def read_EW(files_xls, column="H", row=21):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["EW"])
def read_PTMP(files_xls, column="H", row=22):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["PTMP"])
def read_PTBA(files_xls, column="H", row=23):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["PTBA"])
def read_conacsa(files_xls, column="H", row=24):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Conacsa"])
def read_terminal(files_xls, column="H", row=26):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Terminal"])
def read_moly(files_xls, column="H", row=27):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None,names=["Moly"])
```

**Code**

**

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df1=pd.DataFrame()
df2=pd.DataFrame()
df3=pd.DataFrame()
df4=pd.DataFrame()
df5=pd.DataFrame()
df6=pd.DataFrame()
df7=pd.DataFrame()
df8=pd.DataFrame()
for f in files_xls:
    data = read_produccion(f)
    df = df.append(data)
    data1=read_PTMP(f)*-1
    df1=df1.append(data1)
    data2=read_PTBA(f)*-1
    df2=df2.append(data2)
    data3=read_EW(f)*-1
    df3=df3.append(data3)
    data4=read_conacsa(f)*-1
    df4=df4.append(data4)
    data5=read_terminal(f)*-1
    df5=df5.append(data5)
    data6=read_moly(f)*-1
    df6=df6.append(data6)
    data7=read_inv_i(f)
    df7=df7.append(data7)
    data8=read_inv_f(f)
    df8=df8.append(data8)
    
df_v=pd.concat([df,df4,df1,df5,df6,df2,df3,df7,df8],axis=1)
```

**

**Results**

**Data frame** 19 rows . 9 columns (sorry no formatting)

ProducciónConacsaPTMPTerminalMolyPTBAEWInventario InicialInventario Final020051023.66009115029378.86830236.208022641027.76266113600030259.36430093.60402389956.308484591358030093.60430148.30402458911.3010715914159030148.30429870.00402409971.86592806597029870.00429807.1440689969.631320604081029807.14427521.51406941697.0265000027521.51426453.494022171908.436410173012926453.49425945.06406081690.787580789025945.06424008.284027271519.509610652024008.28424196.784010901576.201234013120024197.24422344.044021691554.86372084516222344.04422371.1840641579.9209491095022371.18419801.264001592.9186207014019801.26417199.504001592.68121705115017199.50414269.82400798.5449032900014269.82412652.28402901019.875993511608512652.28410871.41402080858.866733239488610763.41410845.55401342947.0236319300910845.55410675.534

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the only difference between all your functions are the input parameters you can define the function once and use a list of namedtuples or some other structure to call the function, e.g.:

```py
from collections import namedtuple

# define namedtuple
xls_file_info = namedtuple("XLSFileInfo", "names column row multiplier")

# add named tuples to a list
my_xls_files_info = [
    xls_file_info(["Producción"], "H", 17, 1),
    ...
]


# single function definition
def read_xls_file(files_xls, column, row, names):
    """Read a single cell value from an Excel file"""
    return pd.read_excel(files_xls, skiprows=row - 1, usecols=column, nrows=1, header=None, names=names)

# Create a dictionary with empty dataframes for each cell
df_dict = {str(info.names): pd.DataFrame() for info in my_xls_files_info}

# loop over it all appending each output df to a list
for f in files_xls:
    for info in my_xls_files_info:
        df_dict[str(info.names)] = df_dict[str(info.names)].append(read_xls_file(f, info.column, info.row, info.names) * info.multiplier)

# combine them all together at the end
df_v = pd.concat(list(df_dict.values()), axis=1)
```

Comment: Hi! thank you for your explanation and time. i tried to add more tuple names and i got this error. Same with one tuple name only. 
# add named tuples to a list
my_xls_files_info = [
    xls_file(["Producción"], "H", 17, 1)]
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_14232/3239517523.py in <module>
      1 # define namedtuple
----> 2 xls_file_info = namedtuple("names", "column", "row", "multiplier")
      3 # add named tuples to a list
      4 
      5  TypeError: namedtuple() takes 2 positional arguments but 4 were given

Comment: @P.Lara, I incorrectly instantiated the namedtuple in my answer. I've corrected it and it should work now

Comment: Thank you again, the tuple part now works! the desire final DF is not as expected, It get's NAN for every column that i ADD (Production, EW, PTMP)  i get day 1 for production and NAN NAN for days 2-3 i had this trouble before that's why i wrote code for every df and then concat. I don't know how to post a screenshot here, so I'll edit my first post.

Comment: I missed the `axis=1` in the `pd.concat` call, did you add that in?

Comment: HI thank you again, i add axis 1 to concat and dataframe resulting is one Row and 63 columns. I got Prod / Ew / PTMp columns and then again 21 more times. I tried transpose but i dont get results expected. I tried reset index in df_list before concat and no results

Comment: I edited my answer again. I missed some functionality in your question with the loop

Comment: Thank you, result is EMPY data Frame. I Add Print(df_dict) to see what's happening and it shows {"['Production']": Empty DataFrame Columns: [ ] Index: [ ] ,"['EW']": Empty Dataframe column= [ ] Index= [ ] } and so on...

Comment: and you updated the for loop with the new edit?

Comment: Yes I run everything from the beggining (open path, files, function...)

Comment: I wasn't appending to the dataframes in the dictionary correctly... try again!

Comment: Thank you so much, sorry for late response, i tried and It worked!!! now my code looks more elaborated. Thank you again ,really

Comment: wooh! glad it worked finally lol. Please accept the answer if you're happy with it

Comment: Thank you again ¡¡